# TypeScript application initialisation that uses Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I am building a TypeScript project using a [Webpack GitHub repo](https://github.com/teebot/webpack-typescript). By default the application allows dependency injection and I see no packages installed that provide a IoC so I can only assume TypeScript has some kind of basic DI already? I cannot find documentation on a TypeScript IoC container.

What I'm looking for is some way to setup the application's initialisation that doesn't create a ridiculous DI chain using the `new` operator. Refer to below example:

```
class Stage {
  constructor(
    private light: Light,
  ) { }
}

class App {
  constructor(
    private stage: Stage,
  ) { }
}

class Init {
  constructor(
    private app: App,
  ) { }
}

const init: Init = new Init(new App(new Stage()));
```

It seems like I need to do something with a resolver? Do I have to install something like InversifyJS to achieve this?

I'm sure something like the below code is achievable but how do I tell the IoC container to resolve Init's dependencies? Is there some place I have to create a resolver?

```
const init: Init = new Init();
```

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for, given TS does not have runtime?

Comment: I'm not clear on your question but I've updated my answer as to what I would like to see.

Comment: You cannot do that, TS does not have runtime: types aren't available in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem in the end I ended up using [inversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS) which can be used with Typescript.

The library is quite dense, but it can definitely achieve what you are looking for. 
You will first need to install the following:

```
npm install inversify reflect-metadata --save
```

And in your tsconfig.json file  make the following changes:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6"],
        "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    }
}
```

Then, using your example above:

```
import { injectable, inject } from "inversify";
import "reflect-metadata";

@injectable()
class Stage {
  private light: Light;

  constructor(
    @inject(Light) light: Light,
  ) { 
     this.light = light;
  }
}

@injectable()
class App {
  private stage: Stage;
  constructor(
    @inject(Stage) stage: Stage,
  ) { 
     this.stage = stage;
  }
}

@injectable()
class Init {
  private app: App;
  constructor(
    @inject(App) app: App
  ) { 
    this.app = app;
  }
}
```

You should then create an `inversify.config.ts` file. This is were all of your dependencies will be injected:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Container } from "inversify";
// import all of the Stage/Light/etc. classes also

let DIContainer = new Container();
DIContainer.bind<Stage>(Stage).toSelf();
DIContainer.bind<Light>(Light).toSelf();


export default DIContainer;
```

Finally, go to the file where your `Init` class is instantiated and change it to the following:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import DIContainer from '../src/dependencies';
// import Init class as well

const init: Init = DIContainer.resolve<Init>(Init);
```

It is very much likely that I forgot something or have a bug somewhere but this is the main idea. Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool thanks will check it out. I have seen examples around using InversifyJS I just thought there was maybe a pure TS option.